# Trying to convert json to xml but shows error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, xml, json

I'm trying to convert the json result into xml type. However, it doesn't seems to work. Couldn't find out what's wrong. Please help.

The code is:

```
<script src="../Jquery Autocomplete/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Jquery Autocomplete/jquery.json-2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $(".openModalLink").click(function()
        {
        var start=$(this).parent().parent().find(".start").val();
        var end =$(this).parent().find(".end").val();
        $.ajax(
              {
                type: "POST",
                url: "frmCollegeExamScheduleMst.aspx/ServerSideMethod",
                data: "{'paraml': '" + start + "','param2': '" + end + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                success:function(result)
                {
                    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(result);
                    var xml = $(xmlDoc);
                    var customers = xml.find("Table");
                    var data = new Array();
                    var i =0;
                    $.each(customers, function () 
                    {
                        //do something
                    });
                },
                error: function(err) {
                     alert('Error:' + err.responseText + '  Status: ' + err.status);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Why are you sending XML as JSON? They are two completely different formats.

Comment: What does the `ServerSideMethod` page method return? What is its signature. Also *it doesn't seems to work* is an extremely poor problem description.

Comment: Sorry for the light description. The ServerSideMethod will query the database and returns a dataset. I have used the **return ds.GetXml()** in that method to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify dataType: "json" the response is converted to a JSON object and does not remain a string.

Try removing the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If the response from your AJAX request is `xml` then you should set it accordingly.

```
$.ajax({
  data: {paraml: start, param2: end},
  dataType: "xml",
  success:function(result) {
    var $xml = $(result);
  }
});
```

No need for `contentType` nor concatenating in `data`.

Comment: this one returns an error. The error looks like:
Error:"\u003cNewDataSet\u003e\r\n  \u003cTable\u003e\r\n    \u003cSTU_NAME\u003egagan\u003c/STU_NAME\u003e\r\n    \u003cREG\u003e1\u003c/REG\u003e\r\n  \u003c/Table\u003e\r\n  \u003cTable\u003e\r\n    \u003cSTU_NAME\u003esanthana\u003c/STU_NAME\u003e\r\n    \u003cREG\u003e2\u003c/REG\u003e\r\n  \u003c/Table\u003e\r\n\u003c/NewDataSet\u003e"  Status: 200

Comment: the result from the ServerSideMethod is converted into string format by return ds.GetXml()

Comment: @Prince, That's your XML. Also you haven't shown where the error happens though

Comment: the error appears when the code enters 'success:function(result){alert(result);},'

Comment: yes i tried that one too..but of no help gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
success: function(result) {
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(result.d);
    ...
}
```

Notice the `result.d`. I guess your ASP.NET PageMethod looks like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string ServerSideMethod(string param1, string param2)
{
    DataSet ds = ...
    return ds.GetXml();
}
```

This string is JSON serialized. In order to retrieve it on the client the ASP.NET infrastructure adds the `d` parameter:

```
{"d":"some xml here"}
```

Another thing that you should absolutely change in your code is replace:

```
data: "{'paraml': '" + start + "','param2': '" + end + "'}"
```

with:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ param1: start, param2: end })
```

to ensure that your request parameters are properly JSON encoded. Think for example what will happen if `start = 'foo\'bar'`. You will end up with:

```
data: {param1: 'foo'bar', param2: 'baz'}
```

which as you can see completely breaks your JSON.

Comment: thnx..yes, now everything seem to work fine. But getting error at this step
**success:function(result) {
$xmlDoc = $.parseXML(result.d);}** shows nothing Have tried by removing the .d also

Comment: What's the value of `result.d`?